# How to create SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data(result / output) in a table like this:

```
Project code  project name    associates                   time efforts in days
1             Analytics       amol,manisha,sayali,pooja    (21+17+20+17)=57
```

I need to calculate the time efforts in days. I have done it for February and I have added each persons days he has worked in that month. I mean I have all days minus absentee of any day of all associates.

So, I need to do this by SQL queries.

I have one table which contains all the associates present with dates.

Like this:

```
UID username date
```

So can any one give me a suggestion how I could do this?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide a better understanding of your data model, as well as what you have tried so far, to get a good answer to this question.  For example, are "associates" and "time efforts in day" stored in another table, or are they lists of names/numbers as your question shows?

Comment: Putting **comma-separated** list of items into a single column like in your `asscociates` column is a **really really BAD** design for a relational database. Joining that to the table of `Associates` now is a really annoying and painful exercise..... You should learn about the basics of good relational design - especially about how to **normalize** tables - first normal form says: only put **one atomic value** into each column!

Comment: that first table is not the table... its a result i need to generate from querying on 2nd table which has been given

Comment: the main thing is i need to calculate time efforts column from 2nd table

Comment: @marc_s : sorry for less content... but my question is correct n im havng enough knowledge of that

Comment: @Manisha: How can you tell which users worked on which projects, and when?

Answer (score 0):

It will be a better design to have a separate table to store projectid, team member id and his/her efforts in days. so that you can write a simple join query to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do. Change you tables so you have:

projects

```
project_code  project_name
1             Analytics
```

users

```
UID username date
1   amol
2   manisha
3   sayali
```

projects_users

```
project_code  uid    effort
1             1      21
1             2      17
1             3      20
```

Now you can query the result you asked for like this:

```
SELECT 
  p.project_code,
  p.project_name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.username SEPARATOR ', ') AS associates,
  SUM(pu.effort) effort 
JOIN users AS u
JOIN projects_users AS pu
FROM projects p
GROUP BY project_code
```